# Dissappear content with html

Tags: html

I was playing with some html and thought I might come across something I can use for my website.
Well, while I was playing with html, I came across hiding html content and so I thought of a code that might do it. Here is my code.

```html
<input type = "checkbox"  id = "on"></input>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Dissappear.</button>
<p id = "demo">Html is the best</p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var b = document.getElementById("on").value
if(b =="on"){
document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
}
</script>
```

I was wondering if this was the most efficient way to do this, or if can take about the least amount of storage. If not, please help. Thank you.

Comment: In something as small and simple as this, efficiency doesn't matter at all. The execution time of the code is very short (around 0.000314 seconds).

Comment: I'm sorry you misunderstood so edited my question. I want to know if it is the shortest possible code along with taking up the least space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a checkbox in a wrong way here. We must work with for `checked` property instead

```
if(b =="on"){
  document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

`b=="on"` is a truthy string and is always true.

Also, best is to use `display:none;` instead of `hidden`.

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.display= "none";
```

**FULL WORKING CODE:** Only when the input is checked and we click on the the below div should disappear (This makes more sense in this example). Try this

```html
<input type = "checkbox"  id = "on"></input>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Dissappear.</button>
<p id = "demo">Html is the best</p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
   var b = document.getElementById("on");
   console.log(b);
  if(b.checked){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. So what you are saying is that I should get rid of the if statement and change hidden to none?

Comment: Have updated my answer, I feel this is the best use case of checkbox there. Only when it is checked and we click the button the element below should Disappear :) Thank you. Hope this info is helpful

Comment: Thank you, both of your answers were awesome.

Comment: U are most most welcome. I love to help coders this gives me lots of peace .[answer response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227223/discussion-between-coder9927-and-imran-rafiq-rather).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it really depends on the output your going for. With the code you have, then all that will happen is the element will become transparent. Unfortunately, this also means that the other elements on your page will act like its still their, because it is, you just changed the opacity to 0.

An alternative that would completely remove the element is:

```
function myFunction(){
    var b = document.getElementById("on").value
    if(b =="on"){
       document.getElementById("demo").remove()
    }
}
```

The above will completely delete the element from your page. Further docs here:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_remove.asp

Alternatively again, you could change the display to none. This would combine the above two options, both making it disappear and making it so that other elements will not react to its placement. So unlike the `remove()` method, this will keep the `<p>` in your hard code, but make it visually impossible to route out:

```
function myFunction(){
    var b = document.getElementById("on").value
    if(b =="on"){
       document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

This last one if probably the most "efficient" as it keeps the element in your code and also stops other elements from interacting with it spacially.

Comment: W3Schools can often be inaccurate or outdated. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) instead.

Comment: Your second method seems to be  the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to combine both of your solutions, and here's how it goes. It works beyond expectations of mine

```html
<input type = "checkbox"  id = "on"></input>
<button onclick = "myFunction()">Dissappear.</button>
<p id = "demo">Html is the best</p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
   var b = document.getElementById("on");
   console.log(b);
  if(b.checked){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "visible"
  }
  }

</script>
```