# Is this the best way to calculate a string

Tags: javascript, html

I was playing a bit more with html to add to my website, and following this question [Dissappear content with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689709/dissappear-content-with-html/65690613#65690613), I now have a phone number box and my javascript code tells me how many characters are in the inputs box, but also includes the spaces. Is there anyway for my javascript to calculate how many characters there are excluding the the spaces?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>Click the button to return the number of characters in the string "Hello World!".</p>
  <input id="id"></input>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("id").value
  var str = a
  var n = str.length;
 
  if(n==10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Equal to 10"
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Not equal to 10"
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("id").value.length == 10 ? "Equal to 10" : "Not equal to 10"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: In the network is also a code review page maybe it is more appropriate there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having more verbose code if it makes it easier to understand. Maintainable code is better than "clever" code. But duplication is, in an overwhelming majority of cases, bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit that you can and should do to your code (both the HTML and the JavaScript). Some of it will make it more optimized and some of it has to do with the fact that you are using outdated techniques that should be replaced with the modern, standard approach.

See comments inline for details:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- An HTML document must have a <head> section that 
     contains a non-empty <title> element. -->
<head>
  <title>My Fun Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Click the button to return the number of characters in the string "Hello World!".</p>
  <input id="id"> <!-- input elements don't have a closing tag -->
  
  <!-- Don't use HTML event attributes to bind JavaScript callbacks.
       Do your event binding in JavaScript -->
  <button>Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  // This is the modern way to bind events:
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  
  // Just get your element references once, not each time the function runs
  const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  const input = document.getElementById("id");
  
  function myFunction() {
    // Variables are fine, but they don't help you when you
    // are only going to use their value once. In that case
    // just refer to what you need:
 
    if(input.value.length == 10) {
      // Don't use .innerHTML if you can help it as it has security
      // and performance implications. Since you aren't working with
      // any HTML anyway here, use .textContent
      demo.textContent = "Equal to 10"
    } else {
      demo.textContent = "Not equal to 10"
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostly agree, but I would argue that *Variables don't help you when you are only going to use their value once. In that case just refer to what you need.* may not be true if doing so makes your code harder to understand. I'd much rather have `if(inputIsNotAPhoneNumber)` than `if(input.value.test(/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/))` to name an extreme example.

Comment: @soimon Yes, but what you've forgotten is that in order to write `if(inputIsNotAPhoneNumber)`, you'd still need to write `let inptIsNotAPhoneNumber = /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/`, which means you still have to have the reg. expression written somewhere. So you really haven't made the code any simpler.

Comment: You haven't made it simpler, but you have made it clearer as the regex now has its purpose clearly described.

Comment: @soimon Agreed, but I think that this is an edge case. In this case, I think `input.value.length` is much clearer than `if(n==10) {`, especially since `n = str.length` and `str = a`.

Comment: True, I'm just adding as a side note to the OP that creating variables for one time use is sometimes justified and even advised for better code clarity. It is clear from your example that you didn't mean to deny that to this extend, and I agree that in this case it would not make a lot of sense (especially since `input.value.length` is way more descriptive than `n`).

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

No where in your code do you define `"Hello World"`. Remove the "magic number" `10` (which should be `11`, unless spaces and punctuation do not count) and replace it with the desired word length.

Also, use triple-equals (`===`) for value and type comparison.

```js
const
  targetWord   = "Hello World",
  targetLength = targetWord.length;

function myFunction() {
  const str = document.getElementById("id").value;
  
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = str.length === targetLength
    ? `Equal to ${targetLength}`
    : `Not equal to ${targetLength}`;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to return the number of characters in the string "Hello World!".</p>
<input id="id" value="Hello World" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

The ternary expression is maybe not easy to understand for beginners, but I like them.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    const str = document.getElementById("id").value
    const message = str.length === 10 ? "Equal to 10" : "Not equal to 10"

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much